# jQuery Image Slider and z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, nivo-slider

I'm attempting to get the following site to work:

The "Test" logo appears properly before the jQuery slider transitions to the next picture, which is when it gets shoved behind the new slide. I've tried changing the z-index on a lot of the elements, but nothing seems to work at all. What can I do to fix this?

The slider I'm using is Nivo: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a z-index of 100 or above to div#logo:

```
#header #logo{
    z-index: 100
}
```

It works on the div but not on the image because z-index only works for *positioned* elements. I.e. elements that have position relative, absolute, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cannot believe it was something that simple.